# Trouble accessing internet and MMS with T-Mobile prepaid SIM card in my EU phone

Tags: usa, cellphones, phone-networks

I recently purchased a T-Mobile prepaid SIM card for my trip to the USA, and I'm encountering difficulties accessing the internet and sending MMS messages on my Motorola G22. Back home, my phone carrier is T-Mobile CZ, and it works perfectly fine with 4G in the Czech Republic.

Upon turning on my phone, I receive a message stating, "We see your phone does not have correct settings to access the internet or send MMS. Settings will be sent to your handset," along with device verification codes for the APN and MMS settings.

Following the instructions provided by T-Mobile support, I've waited for the settings to be sent and restarted my phone. However, I am still unable to access the internet, and when I can, it is at an extremely slow speed. Unfortunately, T-Mobile customer support has been unhelpful, recommending that I purchase a USA phone.

Is there any way I can manually configure the APN settings on my Motorola G22 to resolve this issue? Are there any specific APN settings for T-Mobile prepaid SIM cards in the USA that I should be aware of? I'd prefer not to purchase a new phone specifically for this trip. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or insights you can provide.

Thank you!

Note: This question has been phrased by ChatGPT, because my English is not great.

Comment: "recommending that I purchase a USA phone" - this could well be your problem.  Phones are different in USA compared to other places, and they don't always happily switch over.   Have you been into a T-Mobile store and let them look at it and set it up?

Comment: Yeah, the lady in the store, bless her heart, setup our phones, however looked puzzled when confronted with these issues. I do understand that purchasing the US phone would be a catch-all solution, but by god, it's GSM and 4G network both here and in the EU. This phone also sells here.

Comment: I don't know how common it is now, but 4 or 5 years ago I had exactly the same trouble.  Turns out that the cell frequency used on my non-US phone was slightly different to the ones used in the US.  Same phone, same tech, different signals so it wouldn't work.

Comment: _Purchase_ may not be required - airports will often rent phones along with SIM cards, there may be other places as well.  There may be other locations that rent phones.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Motorola G22 [supports 4G bands](https://www.motorola.com/we/smartphones-moto-g-22/p?skuId=441) 1/3/5/7/8/20/38/40/41, while [T-Mobile USA uses bands](https://www.phonearena.com/news/Cheat-sheet-which-4G-LTE-bands-do-AT-T-Verizon-T-Mobile-and-Sprint-use-in-the-USA_id77933) 2/4/5/12/66/71. So, your phone is almost entirely incompatible with T-Mobile USA's 4G network, except in areas where Band 5 is used.

You can [check T-Mobile USA's device compatibility tools](https://www.t-mobile.com/support/coverage/t-mobile-network#tech) if you want, but it seems like the advice to purchase a phone with better US compatibility may be correct.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for the explanation!