# Compatibility of Asus Zenfone 9 in India with major network carriers like Airtel , Jio ,Vi etc

Tags: phone-networks

I am thinking of buying Asus Zenfone 9 from another country and using it in India.So the biggest issue I am facing right now is whether the phone will work well with any major network carriers in India. I did check on the official sites but they show that 5G is  a no go however when I match frequency bands a lot of them do match with those given in technical specs of Asus Zenfone 9 on asus official site and some of the sites show that it is a lot compatible with network carriers in india like https://www.kimovil.com/en/where-to-buy-asus-zenfone-9.

So I want to ask whether this phone will work well with a 4G/5G network carrier like jio for example.I am asking because this is the first time I am doing this and I don't have a lot of idea so I want some guidance on the topic.

By "works well" I mean to say the official network carrier sites don't show the device in its compatibility list maybe because the phone is not released in India. Also I couldn't find anywhere on site about 4G compatible devices that network carrier supports.

Comment: This is not really on topic here, as you do not travel to India with a phone you mainly use outside that country. Besides, I guess you will get better results if you do an internet search in your part of the country with the name and type of the phone and a word like review or compatibility.

Comment: We are not a reviews site, those are off topic here.

Comment: Why was this closed?  It's a perfectly sensible question to ask for any traveller going to India with the phone in question, and it has a widely applicable answer as well: these days pretty much all phones work everywhere.

Comment: Reopened, but it is still no travel question.

Comment: I think it is a travel question. However, the query whether the phone will "work well" when "a lot of them [bands] do match" calls for opinion; what "works well" for you may well be different from how other users might answer the same question. Thus, the question will not generate declarative answers. I think the question is off-topic for that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this was a major issue in the past (2G/3G era), as a rule of thumb, **all modern phones (4G/5G) work everywhere these days**.  The 5G spectrum, for example, is split into [over 100 bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5G_NR_frequency_bands), and while there's variation on what country/operator supports which particular one, the phones themselves are all built to support the whole lot.

The main thing is to ensure that your phone is unlocked in the country you buy it from, which is typically the case as long as you buy it outright from a third party instead of setting up a contract with a Telco.

Comment: this is often but not universally true; we had a [question the other day](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/182108/94507) from someone whose phone does not in fact work on 4G in the United States, despite doing so in the Czech Republic